# Web Accessibility and qTip

Tags: accessibility, qtip

I've recently implemented the [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) jQuery plugin and I absolutely love it.  In doing a code review recently with my boss, Web Accessibility came up in the discussion and specifically qTip was addressed.

Currently I have qTip working such that when hovering over certain icons on my qTip-enabled web pages, a tool tip will display for the user.  Well, that works great for folks that use a mouse, but for those who only use a keyboard, that's not going to work...

I've started to do some research on Web Accessibility and I've read material primarily on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/WAI/).

What I'm looking to do is enable keyboard/screen reader functionality for qTip.

Have any of you done any work with making qTip compatible with Web Accessibility?

I'm **absolutely not** looking for "someone to write the code" here.  Just looking for small examples and any advice on implementing Web Accessibility with the qTip plugin.

Comment: So, it sounds like you want two things: 1) to be able to trigger the qtips via keyboard focus; 2) to ensure that content displayed in the qtip is accessible to screenreaders. Would that be correct? One thing to be aware of is the default behavior of qtip is to pull content from the `title` attribute, [which is not very accessible](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/). You'd want to change that to something else that is more consistently accessible if you're using `@title`.

Comment: @steveax - correct on both of those things.  Does the `title` attribute correspond with the qTip `content` identifier when creating the qTip?  Any ideas on how I could make `content` accessible to a screen reader?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do something along these lines...

Add the content you want in the qTip HTML Markup (rather than in the title attribute):

```html
<p>
<a href="#">
  <span class="hidden">This is the qtip content</span>
  And this is the link content
</a>
</p>
```

Hide the qTip content with CSS (even nicer would be to use something like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to only hide the content if the user had JavaScript enabled, *viz*: `.js .hidden` for the selector):

```css
.hidden {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: -10000px;
   left: -10000px;
   font-size: 1px;
}
```

Then after including jQuery and the qTip scripts, create the qTips using the hidden content for the qTip content and adding `focusin` and `focusout` events to show/hide the qTip:

```js
$('a').qtip({
   content: {
      text: function(api) {
         return $(this).children('.hidden').text();
      }
   }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').focusin(function() {
      $(this).qtip('toggle', true);
   });
   $('a').focusout(function() {
      $(this).qtip('toggle', false);
   });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MnB6Q/

Comment: Great answer. I know tabbing to the item will trigger a focusin event, will it trigger on hover as well?

Comment: @stringy yes, try the fiddle.

Comment: focusin and focusout are working for me with the mouse but not with the keyboard.  I'm using IE 8 specifically.

Comment: The element that is getting tabbed to is an image, btw.  I've put a tabindex of 0 on it to be able to tab to it.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Is the image getting focus?

Comment: It looks like it is (I can tab to it and it gets highlighted when tabbed to), but `onFocus` isn't even working with a simple `alert` on it...if I can tab to it, shouldn't that mean it will focus?

Comment: actually...I take that back...if I put `onFocus="alert('Test')"` right on the image tag, the alert does pop up.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Updated the fiddle to include an image: http://jsfiddle.net/MnB6Q/2/ Works fine for me in IE9/8/7, FireFox and Chrome. Note the changes in the JavaScript to handle the hidden content structure for the image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9689/discussion-between-zack-macomber-and-steveax)